# Typescript class member is undefined

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am trying to write a new typescript class with a generic logger like so:

```
export class ApiCaller {

    protected _logger: Logging;
    constructor() {
        this._logger = new Logging("ApiCaller ");
    }

    public async getData(url): Promise<IItem[]> {
        this._logger.logInfo(url); // Logs without issue

        var result = await $.getJSON(url)
            .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                this._logger.logError("Error: " + err);
                throw new Error(error);
            })
            .always(function () {                
                this._logger.logInfo("Always logs");
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                // processes and returns data
            });
        return result;
    }
```

The call to this._logger.logInfo works fine when we enter the function but the .always shows the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'logInfo' of undefined

Is there anything I can do to make the this._logger available inside .fail, .always and .done?

Comment: It's likely because the function you're passing into `fail` and `always` is changing what `this` points to. You could try: using an arrow function, binding your function to the surrounding context, or storing a reference to `this` outside the function.

Comment: Are you saying the scope of .always is different, is there a way to make the logger class member available inside .always?

Comment: @Aaron, thank you that was the problem, I wish you had created this as an answer so I could mark it as such, not sure how I didn't notice that, too late, porting code from Javascript to Typescript.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your context of `this` is changing due to your functions. If you convert them into arrow functions your `this` will not change.

Something like this should work..

```
export class ApiCaller {

    protected _logger: Logging;
    constructor() {
        this._logger = new Logging("ApiCaller ");
    }

    public async getData(url): Promise<IItem[]> {
        this._logger.logInfo(url); // Logs without issue

        var result = await $.getJSON(url)
            .fail((jqxhr, textStatus, error) => {
                var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                this._logger.logError("Error: " + err);
                throw new Error(error);
            })
            .always(() => {               
                this._logger.logInfo("Always logs");
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                // processes and returns data
            });
        return result;
    }
```